# jQuery UI resizable snap to size

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

I have a left-side navigation which is resizable. The default width is 200 and I want the resizer to snap to that width. Currently I have this if-clause which is working fine but I don't know how to snap to that width programmatically.

```
resize: function (event, ui) {
    if(Math.abs(200 - ui.size.width) <= 20){
        // snap to 200 width
    }
}
```

Would be great if someone could help me here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok got it working. Simply set the width of the element to 200. It has a tolerance of 15px so if the element is between 185 and 215px it will snap to 200px.

```
$("#left").resizable({
minWidth: 60,
handles: "e",
resize: function (event, ui) {
    if(Math.abs(200 - ui.size.width) <= 15){
        $("#left").css("width", 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: @CyrilALFARO: No, you locked the resizing to 20-200.

Comment: Great code! New to Jquery UI, didn't know that's how `ui.size.width` works! Learned something today!

Answer (score 0):

As there : http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#max-min you can use this :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#left" ).resizable({
      maxWidth: 200,
      minWidth: 20
    });
});
```

Comment: That would make it not even resizable.

Comment: But it's the better way to resize it, dont forget to put #left ;)

Comment: With that code I can't even resize the navigation. It should resize and just snap to the width 200

Comment: You want to inverse the resize ? If no just set minWidth to 20

Comment: That's actually not the point I wanted to achieve. I want a normal resize with a snap to the width:200. Your code is limiting the snap from 20-200.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like `$(ui).width(200);` ? 
Please note that I have no idea about what is `ui`in your code so you may have to adapt the `jQuery`selector.

Comment: No problem, but ithink it might worth something to have a look at the third answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would check for a width within a range so that the 'snap' happens from either side.

```
resize: function (event, ui) {
    if(ui.size.width >= 180 && ui.size.width <= 220){
        // snap to 200 width
    }
}
```