# jQuery draggable in grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, resizable

Maybe it is a bug report or maybe it's my fault. After trying for a whole day I don't know the answer anymore.

As you can try via the link below my resizable grid panels are not working well. Moving the boxes in the grid works perfect but when resizing it looks like the resizable has a delay or something. When you move your cursor fast it just doesn't snap anymore. If you move the panel box by box (and release the mouse after moving one box) it works fine.

What did I try so far: Upgrading to the newest version of jQuery and jQuery-UI, trying different grid sizes (the grid itself is 40x40, the draggable grid is 40x40 but to let the resizable work I had to change the grid size to 70x70. Why is that?)

```
$(function(){
  $(".panel")
    .draggable({ grid: [40,40], containment: $('.container') })
    .resizable({ grid: [70,70], containment: $('.container') })
});
```

Is this a known problem or did I do something wrong?

[jQuery demo](http://tools.dev.hoorhetwoord.nl/snip/grid.html)
[YouTube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59-5QKV2aC0)

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121727/jquery-ui-resizable-snap-to-size

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to adjust the `size{ width, height}` manually during resize.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1j71x38j/

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $(".panel ")
    .draggable({
      grid: [40, 40],
      containment: $('.container')
    })
    .resizable({
      //grid: [70, 70],
      containment: $('.container'),
      resize: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.size.width % 40 != 0) {
          var off = ui.size.width % 40;
          if (off <= 20) {
            ui.size.width = ui.size.width - off;
          } else {
            ui.size.width = ui.size.width + off;
          }
        }
        if (ui.size.height % 40 != 0) {
          var off = ui.size.height % 40;
          if (off <= 20) {
            ui.size.height = ui.size.height - off;
          } else {
            ui.size.height = ui.size.height + off;
          }
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Using Mod 40, I can determine if the width or height match your grid. If the remainder is less then half, we reduce the size to the next grid; otherwise, we increase the size to the next grid.

Comment: Wow thanks, you helped me a lot. After playing with it for a few hours I have only one thing that I can't resolve: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTJ7GyD7hJw)

When I pull on the bottom to resize the size in width changes. And another thing (not on video) is when I want to go full width I can't. I made a container of 800*800 and wanted to make the panel 800px width but it stopped for the last grid block (40px). Is that something jQuery containment does or has that something to do with your code?